# Why do pointer / variable memory addresses not change?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = new int;
    cout << "Memory address of ptr:" << ptr << endl;
    cin.get();
    delete ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run this program, I get the same memory address for `ptr`.  Why?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be different?

Comment: I would expect that as other processes / threads have memory allocated to them, memory addresses would be changed.  The fact that I could add variables, recompile, start other processes, whatever - and yet the memory addresses stayed constant - seems like it warrants some type of explanation = )

Comment: Remember that due to virtual memory, each process operates in its own unique address space, which is unaffected by any other process.

Comment: @CalvinFroedge; The other processes are irrelevant.

Comment: Added to "to learn" list: virtual memory

Comment: @CalvinFroedge Modern operating systems are a far cry from real-mode DOS :)

Comment: @pst Gotta start somewhere, right?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that is an answer (the most correct one so far).

Comment: Restart the computer and it would change :)

Comment: @LokiAstari: It's an answer now!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*[Note: my answer assumes you're working with a modern OS that uses a virtual memory system.]*

Due to virtual memory, each process operates in its own unique address space, which is independent of and unaffected by any other process.  The address you get from `new` is a **virtual address**, and is generated by whatever your compiler's implementation of `new` chooses to do.<sup>*</sup>  There's no reason this couldn't be deterministic.

On the other hand, the **physical address** associated with your virtual memory address will most likely be different every time, and will be affected by all sorts of things.  This mapping is controlled by the OS.

---

<sub>* `new` is probably implemented in terms of `malloc`.</sub>

Comment: Although, it should be noted that newer operating systems have [support for Address Space Layout Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) so other factors might apply.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say it's mostly coincidence. As the memory allocator/OS can give you whatever address it wants.

The addresses you get are obviously not uniformly random (and is highly dependent on other OS factors), so it's often to get the same (virtual) address several times in the row.

So for example, on my machine: Window 7, compiled with VS2010, I get different addresses with different runs:

```
00134C40
00124C40
00214C40
00034C40
00144C40
001B4C40
```

Comment: The underlying physical memory is probably different each time. But because the hardware virtualizes the address space it is probably always the same within the processes. But as you say highly Hardware/OS dependent.

Answer (score 2):

This is an artifact of your environment. <del>The cin.get() suggests to me that you are compiling and executing in Visual Studio, which provides an unusually predictable runtime environment.</del> When I compile and run that code on my linux, two executions gave two different addresses.

ETA:
In comments you expressed an expectation that different processes could obtain the same memory address and that this address would be inaccessible to your program. In any modern operating system this is not the case, because the operating system is providing each process with *virtual memory* address spaces.

Only the operating system sees the true hardware addresses, and maintains virtual memory maps for each program, redirecting virtual addresses to physical addresses. Therefore, an arbitrary number of different processes can hold data in the same virtual address, while the operating system maps that address to a separate physical address for each process.

This guarantees that process A cannot read or write to memory in use by process B without a special provision enabling such access (such as by instructing the OS to map certain virtual memory in certain processes to the same physical memory). It allows the operating system to make different kinds of memory hardware transparent to programs.

It also allows the OS to move a program's data around behind its back to optimize system performance. 
Classical example: Moving data that hasn't been used for some time to a special file on the hard disk. This is sometimes called the *page file*.

Memory maps are typically broken up into *pages*: Blocks of contiguous memory of a certain size (the *page size*). Data held within a page of virtual address space is usually also contiguous in physical memory, but if data runs over a page boundary, information that appears contiguous in virtual memory could easily be separated. If a C/C++ program enters undefined behavior, it may attempt to access memory in a page that the OS has not mapped to physical memory. This will cause the OS to generate an error.

Comment: No, with g++.  cin.get() is just so the program requires me to hit the return key before it exists.

Comment: @Calvin The program exists as soon as you run it. Did you mean to say 'exits'? With Linux you can run in a terminal which won't close itself as soon as a program finishes execution. I should improve the answer anyways, check it again in a bit.